# Combining sources. Calculate load current and load voltage. Calculate the load power, the power generated (or dissipated) by each source

Tags: voltage, power, current, current-source, voltage-source

Stuck on this question. Not sure how to calculate the voltage and power across the current sources.[image: current and voltage source in circuit]

In question c the current from the 1A and 3A sources combine to 4A but I don't know how to find the voltage across the current sources to calculate the power. Question d is the same.

Comment: Clue: It's the voltages across the resistors you need to find, not across the current sources.

Answer (score 0):

Hints...

- In scenario (c) the net current into the resistor load is the addition of the two current sources
- Can you see what it will be in scenario (d)?
- The voltage source has nothing to do with what current flows into the load resistor
- However, the voltage source will "be in play" when working out what the voltage across the current source(s) is.
- Power = volts x amps

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be superposition.

Analyze impact of each source separately, replacing others by their ideal internal resistances.  Current source is ∞ (open circuit) and voltage source is 0Ω (short circuit).

You only have one resistor, so this is easy.

For 1A source:

3A current source is an open circuit (ideal internal resistance is ∞, or an open circuit) and 2.5V voltage source is a short ciruit (ideal internal resistance is 0Ω, or a short circuit).

Circuit becomes:

[image: schematic]

Solve using Ohm's Law.

$$ V_R = 1A \times 2Ω = +2V$$

Repeat for other sources.  Watch signs (as in direction of currents).  Some will be + and -.

Add all Voltages (or currents) to get impact of all sources.